# Issues with Kotlin code causing app to crash silently

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

this is kotlin code, that crashes my app , i know because i trired running the app without this code and the app runs smooth.

btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_Login)
btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSign_Up)

```
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this,SignUp::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

can any one please explain why it keeps crashing, i might be declaring variable in wrong way.

class Login : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var edtEmail : EditText
private lateinit var edtPassword : EditText
private lateinit var btnLogin : EditText
private lateinit var btnSignUp : EditText

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

    edtEmail = findViewById(R.id.edt_email)
    edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edt_password)
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
    btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_Login)
    btnSignUp = findViewById(R.id.btnSign_Up)

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this,SignUp::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
}
```

}

The part in the comments is the problem

Comment: Need to see your stack trace.

Comment: share crash log error, or XML code with question

Comment: Sorry guys i'm using EditText instead of Button.